# The prefix *sub*

Tags: prefixes

The prefix **sub** appears in many words, such as *subway* and *substantial*.

For **subway**, I take it as the **way** that is completely different from the **way** that I get used to. Moreover it is not the main way.
Other words with *sub*, like subcategories and subscript, they all seem that **sub** makes the concept inferior.

But **substantial** turns the concept upside down. It means completely the opposite.

So, could someone shed some light on this for me please?
So how do we know when sub is a prefix and when it isn't?

Comment: The "sub" in *substantial* is not a prefix. All words that begin with the three letters need not necessarily belong to that group. The logic of *sub-* is therefore irrelevant here. Think *substance* when you think of *substantial*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sub in subway means beneath. A subway is originally and still in most places underground, which is a synonym for the subway in British English

Sub in [substantial](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=substantial) is not really a prefix

[substantial](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=substantial)

> mid-14c., "ample, sizeable," from Old French substantiel (13c.), from Latin substantialis "having substance or reality, material," from substantia (see substance). Meaning "existing, having real existence" is from late 14c.

[substance](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=substance&searchmode=none)

> c.1300, "essential nature," from Old French substance (12c.), from Latin substantia "being, essence, material," from substans, present participle of substare "stand firm, be under or present," from sub "up to, under" + stare "to stand," from PIE root *sta- "to stand"

Perhaps you want to look at [English words prefixed with sub](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category%3aEnglish_words_prefixed_with_sub-)

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan for your answer. I am not a native speaker. So I am wondering how tell this situation from others that **sub** in *substantial* is not a prefix.

Comment: @Alex, _sub-_ is a prefix in ‘subtantial’ as well—it’s just that it’s not as transparent as in most other words, because ‘substantial’ is first and foremost a derivation from ‘substance’, in which word the meaning of the prefix has been lost.